# Vue Firestore - how to get the sum() of all columns of today date?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Im new in Vue and Firestore. Im trying to retrieve data with calculating all columns. But cant find any way yet. Also in the firestore documentation dosent have any resource about that.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried, explaining why it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Implement SUM() function of SQL in cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340402/how-to-implement-sum-function-of-sql-in-cloud-firestore)