# Iterate through collection items and sum property of each document while being subscribed for a collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection `counters`, each `counter` document has a collection `actions`. Each `action` has a `step` property which is a Number.

Here's how  I get all (subscribe) `counters`

```
firestoreRef.onSnapshot(
  (countersSnapshot) => {
    const arrayOfCounters = [];
    if (!countersSnapshot.empty) {
      countersSnapshot.forEach((counterDocument) =>
        arrayOfCounters.push(counterDocument),
      );
    }
    setCounters(arrayOfCounters); // <- this is React.useState()[1]
  },
  (e) => console.error(e),
);
```

I used to have `actions`' as an array in `counter` and I would get "`currentValue`" (which is a sum of all `step` values in `actions`) like this:

```
const getCurrentValue = (initialValue, actions, step) => {
  if (!actions.length) {
    return initialValue;
  }

  return actions.reduce((a, b) => {
    return b.type === TYPE_INCREMENT ? a + step : a - step;
  }, initialValue);
};
```

However I decided to transform `actions` to a Firestore collection. How should I get all counters and their current value, while also being subscribed to this so I get real-time updates?

Comment: Hi @IvankaTodorova is this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340402/how-to-implement-sum-function-of-sql-in-cloud-firestore) helpful to what you are looking for? As far as I could understand, you would like to sum the values of this subcollection - `actions` - within your main collection - `counters` - is that correct? If not, please, let me know, by adding further clarification.

Comment: @gso_gabriel Thanks for your reply! I actually did it by subscribing to each `counter.ref.collection('actions')` but didn't think of all those queries being made for each of the documents. The answer you linked is so much more helpful!

Comment: Hi @IvankaTodorova nice to hear it helped you! If it helped you fix the issue, would you mind if a post it as answer - including more details - so you can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Posting as Community Wiki answer, based in the comments.

Following examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340402/how-to-implement-sum-function-of-sql-in-cloud-firestore), should provide a good understanding and help with ideas to solve the issue. For example, subscribing to each `counter.ref.collection('actions')` might be a solution, however, take in account of all the queries will be made for each of the documents. I believe this link should help, as it's a similar cases and provide multiples alternatives - with code samples included - of solutions.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, I am still implementing the solution using Cloud Functions, once I am sure I completely understand them & my code works, will definitely post an update!