# Flutter Calculating the total amount in the cart? (Using Firestore to Store Cart Products)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firestore to store Cart Items and want to get total amount of price of all the products but unable to get how total price and and Show in Footer. Is Ther any code to total qauntity and rate of each product and total them.

```
Widget fetchData(){
  final String uid=FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email!;
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('$uid'+'cart')
        .snapshots(),
    builder:
        (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Center(
          child: Text("Something is wrong"),
        );
      }
try{
 if (snapshot.data!.docs.length==0) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Your Truck Is Empty'),),
          body: Center(
            child:Column(children: [ Image.asset('assets/images/empty.png'),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Back to Home'))],)
          ),
        );
      }
}catch(exception){
      
}
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Truck'),),
  body: Center(
    child:
ListView.builder(
          itemCount:
          snapshot.data == null ? 0 : snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot _documentSnapshot =
            snapshot.data!.docs[index];
           
            return Card(
              elevation: 2,
              child: ListTile(
                leading:Column(children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Text(_documentSnapshot['name']),
                   Text('Qty:'+'${_documentSnapshot['quantity']}'),
                    Text('Total:Rs.${_documentSnapshot['quantity']* _documentSnapshot['rate']}'.toString()),
                    
                ],),
                 
                title: Column(children: [
                   Text(
                  "\Rs. ${_documentSnapshot['mrp']}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
                ),
                 Text(
                  "\Rs. ${_documentSnapshot['rate']}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
                ),
                ],),
               
             
                  onTap: () {
                   FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('$uid'+'cart').doc(_documentSnapshot['id']).delete();
    
                  },
                    
 

                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
  )
   
);

        }
    
  );
}
```

Please I'm stuck, I'm trying to stream product price from cart and sum up to get the total... here is my code...

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340402/how-to-implement-sum-function-of-sql-in-cloud-firestore) help you? Check [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) from the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for advice but I didn't got my answer there

Answer (score 0):

I have created a collection name like cart_email. So, that every user has a unique cart collection.
This is the code where I am calculating the total amount.

```
  int amount = 0;
  
  void fetchPrice() async {
    String collection_name = "cart_${auth.currentUser?.email}";
    final data = await fb.collection(collection_name).get();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>?>? documentData = data?.docs.map((e) => e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?).toList(); //working

    int len = documentData!.length;
    int price = documentData![0]!['price'];
    int? sum = 0;

    for( int i = 0 ; i < len; i++ ) {
      sum = (sum! + documentData![i]!['price']) as int?;
      // print('i ' + i.toString() + ' amt: ' + sum.toString());
    }
    setState(() {
      amount = sum!;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

num totalPriceFinal = 0;

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  const Cart({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Cart> createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    calculatingTotalPrice();
    super.initState();
  }

  calculatingTotalPrice() async {
    num totalPrice = 0;
    final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestoreInstance
        .collection("users-cart-items")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
        .collection("items")
        .get();

    for (int i = 0; i < qn.docs.length; i++) {
      totalPrice = totalPrice + num.parse(qn.docs[i]["price"]);
      totalPriceFinal = totalPrice;          
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  fetchData(String collectionName) {
    num lastElement = 0;

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(collectionName)
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
          .collection("items")
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Center(
            child: Text("Something is wrong"),
          );
        }

        return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data == null ? 0 : snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
              lastElement = snapshot.data!.docs.length;

              return Column(
                children: [
                  Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Text(documentSnapshot['name']),
                      title: Text(
                        "\$ ${documentSnapshot['price']}",
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.red),
                      ),
                      trailing: GestureDetector(
                        child: const CircleAvatar(
                          child: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection(collectionName)
                              .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email)
                              .collection("items")
                              .doc(documentSnapshot.id)
                              .delete()
                              .then((value) => calculatingTotalPrice());
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (index == lastElement - 1)
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Total Price :  $totalPriceFinal",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.green.shade700, fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              );
            });
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: fetchData("users-cart-items"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?