# React native - firestore array and map

Tags: react-native

Problem with reading and summing values from the list of products.

hello. I am new to react native. I don't know how to access the data. I've searched but can't find a solution. I have a collection 'products' and in it is the name of the list of products and in the array there are individual products and price. What should the query look like in general to fetch individual lists and add prices in individual lists?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYuKn.png)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340402/how-to-implement-sum-function-of-sql-in-cloud-firestore

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.